# Array of point objects to arrays of X and Y

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of `point` objects:

```
const points = [ {x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 1, y: 1}, ...]
```

I want to convert them to arrays of x and y:

```
const x = [0, 1, ...];
const y = [0, 1, ...];
```

I could use 2 maps:

```
const x = points.map(v => v.x);
const y = points.map(v => v.y);
```

But that needs 2 iterations over the array. I can do a loop:

```
const x = [];
const y = [];
for (let i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
   const pt = points[i];
   x.push(pt.x);
   y.push(pt.y);
}
```

That seems overly verbose and potentially slow (all those push backs).
Is there a better method?

Comment: Remember that internal to `map` something fairly equivalent to the `push` is going to happen anyway.  Have you tested and found that those two iterations cause you a significant slowdown?

Answer (score 1):

At least you need some pushing to the wanted result sets. This solution uses an object for pushing to the right array.

```js
const
    points = [{ x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 1, y: 1 }],
    x = [],
    y = [],
    values = { x, y };
    
points.forEach(o => Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => values[k].push(v)));

console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

Basically the same, but with known keys.

```js
const
    points = [{ x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 1, y: 1 }],
    x = [],
    y = [],
    values = { x, y },
    keys = Object.keys(values);
    
points.forEach(o => keys.forEach(k => values[k].push(o[k])));

console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can do this reasonably easily, say like this:

```js
const points = [{x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 2, y: 3}, {x: 3, y: 5}, {x: 4, y: 7}, {x: 5, y: 11}]

const {x, y} = points.reduce(
  ({x, y}, pt) => ({x: [...x, pt.x], y: [...y, pt.y]}),
  {x: [], y: []}
)

console.log(x)
console.log(y)
```

there is the bigger question you need to consider of *why* you want to do this.  The original structure is flexible and useful, and you already have it in memory.  The new structures depends upon shared indices, which is often difficult to work with and can easily get out of sync.  Is there a strong reason not to use the original structure?

Comment: Yes - I am passing the array of points to a React component from the react-plotly library. It requires an array of X and an array of Y data.

Comment: Makes sense.  Then many of the techniques here would help you, but I wouldn't be surprised if two separate `map` calls are actually faster.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can do make something like that :

```js
const points = [ {x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 1, y: 1}];

const t = points.map(item => {
 return Object.values(item);
})

const x = t[0];
const y = t[1];
console.log(x,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x= [], y = [], points = [{ x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 1, y: 10 }];

points.forEach(({x: x1, y: y1}) => (x.push(x1), y.push(y1)))

console.log(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to accumulate result in a multi-dimensional array.

```js
const points = [ {x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 1, y: 1}],
      [x,y] = points.reduce((r,o) => {
        Object.values(o).forEach((v,i) => r[i].push(v));
        return r;
      },[[],[]]);
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```